# Are there any method to multivariate forecasting except for VAR?

Tags: forecasting, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

I mean 2 or more dependent variables as multivariate.I know we can use VAR or VARMA to forecasting but are there another method except for ANN and VAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a multivariate time series, you can use basically any method that you would use for multivariate cross-sectional data, in addition to methods specific to time series (such as VARMA or more generally, state-space models). For example,

- Multivariate regression is a method used for cross-sectional data when you have multiple dependent variables. VAR is a special case of a multivariate regression: in a VAR, the regressors are bound to be lagged values of the dependent variables (though you can have other variables, too, in which case a VAR becomes a VARX).

As you mentioned, you can use artificial neural networks. You can also use k nearest neighbours, support vector machines, tree-based methods and other. In my understanding, dealing with time series instead of cross-sectional data is not limiting the model selection; rather, it adds new possibilities (like VARMA).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I already mentioned them.Can you add classical statistic model like VAR,VARMA?

Comment: You asked for forecasting methods, and I gave you k nearest neighbours, support vector machines and tree-based methods. Now you say you want "classical statistic" models, but this can be tricky to define. Could you give any examples of models for non time series data that you would consider classical?

Comment: Ok then there is not except for VARMA and VAR for multivariate time series as classical statistic models.@richard thank you so much

Comment: @mrt, I added state-space models which are more general than VARMA; they include, among other, VAR models with time-varying coefficients.